# The selected item is lost after searching-Bootstrap table after

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap table for table management. I have a table with checkboxes, so I have used `data-click-to-select = "true"` I also have a search bar I used `data-search = "true"` When I select an item and I do a search I lose the item that was selected.

In the attached link an example: you select the first element "bootstrap-table" and after you put "b" in zone of search then the element will no longer be selected

`1999`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter1992/qhwhhbf3/)**

Any idea plz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `data-maintain-selected="true"` to keep the selected checkbox.

Updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhwhhbf3/1/).

```
<table data-maintain-selected="true" data-toggle="table" data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/" data-click-to-select="true" data-search="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="name">Name</th>
      <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

You can read more about `data-maintain-selected` **[here](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)**.

Comment: @elogriamine, nice. You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
data-maintain-meta-data="true"
```

> ...to maintain the following meta data on change page and search.

You can read more about data-maintain-selected [here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#maintainmetadata).